# does chrome handle undefined differently?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, undefined

My Asp masterpage has this code:

```
<script>
    if (theForm !== undefined) { // <<== line 746: error
        theForm.onsubmit = ...bla bla... ;
    }
</script>
```

The Chrome console reports the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: theForm is not defined   bla.aspx:746
```

My question is: is this a wrong way of detecting if a name is undefined? Or is this handled differently by Chrome?

(NB: Firefox console does not report an error, but still stops processing following JS code of this script block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a distinction between a variable being declared but having a value of `undefined` and a variable that was never even declared. I'm guessing your scenario is the latter. Use the typeof operator for this.

```
if(typeof(theForm) !== 'undefined'){ //typeof returns a string
```

Comment: `typeof` isn't a function so it doesn't need parentheses.

Comment: @JLRishe I'm aware, thank you. But it takes them all the same and I prefer to use them because I feel it improves readability.

Comment: @dgeare still strange that `if(undeclaredvar)` causes a ReferenceError and probably `somefunction(undeclaredvar)` too, while `typeof(undeclaredvar)` is fine. `typeof undeclaredvar ` is perhaps more clear that it is not a function. Comparing with a hard-coded string is kind of a hack,why can't we just write `if (defined somevar)` ?

Answer (score 2):

The message `Uncaught ReferenceError: theForm is not defined`

should be interpreted as

`theForm is not` **`declared`**

Why?
Basically, a variable can be `undefined` (but declared) and can be not declared at all.

Example

1. Declared and `undefined`

```js
var foo;        // if a value would be assigned (i.e.: var foo = 3), then it wouldn't be undefined
console.log(foo);
```

2. Not declared (it will throw an error)

```js
console.log(foo); // <-- foo was never declared
```

---

How to **fix** it?

Use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) like this:

```js
  console.log('Is undefined:', typeof foo === 'undefined');
```

Comment: I had case 2,but a run-time ReferenceError, not a compile error. Also, dgeare answered faster, so I accepted his answer, although I appreciate your code snippets

Comment: @Roland, thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer for avoiding any misleading understanding :) I'm glad you found useful the snippets. Don't worry about checking the answer as accepted. I appreciate the upvotes too :) Sometimes a more elaborated post takes more time than other.

Comment: Good sport, thanks. Your first sentence in the answer is the key. You could have submitted your short answer to be first,then edit to elaborate on it :-)